# Migradoc - Text Appended After Header Appears Over Header

Tags: c#, migradoc

I am using the following code to create a PDF with a header where there is an image on the left and then information about the document to the right of the image:

```
var header = section.Headers.Primary.AddTable();
header.AddColumn("1in");
header.AddColumn("6in");
var headerRow = header.AddRow();
headerRow.HeadingFormat = true;

var logo = headerRow.Cells[0].Elements.AddImage(@"...image.png");
logo.Width = "48pt";
logo.LockAspectRatio = true;
logo.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Line;
logo.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
logo.Top = ShapePosition.Top;
logo.Left = ShapePosition.Left;
logo.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.TopBottom;

headerRow.Cells[1].Elements.AddParagraph($"Approved{Environment.NewLine}Generation Timestamp: {DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt}");
var documentDetails = headerRow.Cells[1].Elements.AddParagraph();
var sentenceParts = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Name: ", "Smith, John" },
    { "Date Of Birth: ", "1999-01-01" },
    { "ID: ", "123456" }
};

var boldedFont = new Font(document.Styles.Normal.Font.Name, 6) {Bold = true};
var unboldedFont = new Font(document.Styles.Normal.Font.Name, 6);
foreach (var sentencePart in sentenceParts)
{
    documentDetails.AddFormattedText(sentencePart.Key + " ", boldedFont);
    documentDetails.AddFormattedText(sentencePart.Value + " ", unboldedFont);
}
```

This works great in that the document looks like how I'd expect it to look. Where the issue starts is if I try to add text to the document body afterward using the following:

```
section.AddParagraph("Here is some test text that should appear after the header.");
```

What's happening is that the text appears over the header instead of at the top of the header's bottom, which is what I'd expect. What am I missing? Is the document's header's height not being calculated to fit the size of its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved by explicitly adding space before paragraph.

**An example code snippet for adding space before paragraph:**

```
Paragraph myParagraph = section.AddParagraph("Here is some test text that should appear after the header.");
myParagraph.Format.SpaceBefore = "10cm";
```

**More information:**

http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx

Answer (score 0):

MigraDoc does not calculate the height of the header. It is up to you to set the top margin to reserve space for the header.

Quite often the first page has a larger header. In that case, using SpaceBefore for the first paragraph on the first page is a good workaround.

Update (April 3, 2023):
There is a breaking change with PDFsharp & MigraDoc 6.0.0 (preview packages and source release today): SpaceBefore is now ignored for the first paragraph on a page.
To continue using the old trick, you have to insert a dummy paragraph before the paragraph where you want to use SpaceBefore if it is the first paragraph in the section.